# Can't spread on a custom object map type

Tags: typescript

I have this utility interface:

```
export interface ObjectMap<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

When I try to spread a type that implements it, I get an error:

```
export const saveLocalizationDeltas = (
  namespace: string,
  deltas: ObjectMap<string>,
) => {
    ...
    const updated = localizations
      ? { ...localizations, ...deltas[language] } // Spread types may only be created from object types
      : deltas[language];
```

I can do this without issue:

```
Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(localizations), deltas[language])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is wrong with the code.

`deltas[language]` - is a string, not an object and it's a bit strange to spread it.

`{ ...someObj, ..."string" }` - unexpected code.

I think you wanted to spread `...deltas` itself, or you need to define its type better, if it's an object of objects of strings, then it should be `deltas: ObjectMap<ObjectMap<string>>`.

---

`Object.assign` has `(target: object, ...sources: any[]): any;` signature. That's why it accepts strings.